# biolinum on Miktex

Tags: fonts, miktex

I'm using Miktex on Windows an I want to use "biolinum" as a default font.

I have tried this instruction:

```
\usepackage{biolinum}
```

But it doesn't work.

I have tried also:

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

and nothing happened.

Comment: Please, please, please always create a **compilable** code, do not post only code snippets ...

Comment: In addition, you might want to specify in more detail, *how* things don't work for you. It could be helpful to check the `.log` file and report anything unusual.

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{biolinum}
```

Should work, as per the `libertine` manual, page 2.